# How to use ">" in msbuild proj file

Tags: msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I need to use ">" inside a tag in msbuild proj file to redirect devenv output to a file. My code is

`<Exec Command='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build "Release|x86" ..\MySolution.sln ">" log.txt'/>`

But it does not work for me. Please answer me how to use ">" inside xml tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the magic of [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)!

```
&gt; or &#62;
&lt; or &#60;
&quot; or &#34;
&apos; or &#39;
&amp; or &#38;
```

Output:
> or > 
< or < 
" or " 
' or ' 
& or &

```
<Exec Command='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build "Release|x86" ..\MySolution.sln &gt; log.txt'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `>` to the entity charset `&amp;gt;` in xml, else it interprets the symbol as a tag termination character.

Comment: Hey you forgot to escape the second one in a {code} block :o